# C# - ListView always shows duplicates

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I found nothing useful so far, so I hope someone could help me.
I loop through the records in my database to grab the informations I need but everytime, the ListView shows duplicates of the Item.

My Code for getting the information:

```
private void fetchEmails()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string query = "SELECT emails.emailsender, emails.message FROM emails, users WHERE emails.emailreciever='" + Variables.email + "'";

        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    //MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    ad.Fill(ds, "emails");

                    dt = ds.Tables["emails"];
                    int i;

                    listView1.Items.Clear();

                    for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        listView1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
                        listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of duplicate are you getting? Will you include in the question, the duplicate records-- the exact value of listView1.Items?

Comment: @Larry31 Using multiple tables in the `FROM` caluse is really messy - `FROM emails, users WHERE` (from your question). Do you really need to do this? I suspect there is pretty big chance to get unexpected records because the way this query is executed. If you need the data from both tables better try `JOIN` or even making two separate queries for each table rather than using two tables like this in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @JerdineSabio If I have one record in Database it just displays this one record two times